# Unity error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `UnitySampleAssets._2D.Camera2DFollow.Characters'

Tags: c#

I realize that there are hundreds of pages relating to this error. I have however already looked at many of them and have been unable to find one that pertains to my particular issue, so if this is a duplicate thread I do appologize.  I am trying to modify the 2D camera script provided by unity to choose its "target" (the game object it follows) to whatever character the user selects.  I am new to C# so I don't really know too well how to deal with this error.  I posted the whole code just in case, but the error should likely be found within the first 10 lines or so

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D
{

    public class Camera2DFollow : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private string character = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Character")
        public Transform target = Transform.Find(character);
        public float damping = 1;
        public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
        public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
        public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

        private float offsetZ;
        private Vector3 lastTargetPosition;
        private Vector3 currentVelocity;
        private Vector3 lookAheadPos;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            lastTargetPosition = target.position;
            offsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
            transform.parent = null;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {

            // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
            float xMoveDelta = (target.position - lastTargetPosition).x;

            bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) >                    lookAheadMoveThreshold;

            if (updateLookAheadTarget)
            {
                lookAheadPos =       lookAheadFactor*Vector3.right*Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
            }
            else
            {
                lookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(lookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime*lookAheadReturnSpeed);
            }

            Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + lookAheadPos + Vector3.forward*offsetZ;
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref currentVelocity, damping);

            transform.position = newPos;

            lastTargetPosition = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post `PlayerPrefs.GetString` and `Transform.Find` as well.

Comment: "error should likely be found within the first 10 lines or so"... precision is important here. *You* should know exactly what line the error occurs on, and thus you should tell us exactly which line it occurs on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize a variable with another variable

```
private string character = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Character")
public Transform target = Transform.Find(character); // <---- Trying to access 'character' which is a variable
```

instead put it in the `Start()` method

```
private void Start()
{
    target = Transform.Find(character); // <---- here
    lastTargetPosition = target.position;
    offsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
    transform.parent = null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that solved that issue.  i'm still trying to work out some bugs, as now  transform.Find(character); is not not working and target remains null ingame. but thanks again for your help